# Why does vba not see the value of a cell during a nested For loop?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

'I'm trying to use a For loop to use the i index to see which columns to process data from in an ActiveSheet and calculate a gradient in steps from a graph trendline. It sees the value of the `ActiveSheet.Cells(i,24).Value`  without the second For loop nested inside but otherwise the value is blank when it should be "Grad" on certain i values when i try to debug it.

Code below:

```
For i = 1 To 50


    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 24).Value = "Grad" Then

    Cells(i & "26:" & "i" & "66").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("B112").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

             For j = 112 To 149

'Values Selected in batches of 4 points to calculate gradient.

                  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate

                    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='X540'!$A$" & j & ":$A$" & j + 3
                    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='X540'!$B$" & j & ":$B$" & j + 3

                With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(2).Chart

                Set objTrendline = .SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)

                    With objTrendline
                        .DisplayEquation = True

                    strEquation = .DataLabel.Text


                    Range("B154") = strEquation
                    End With

                End With

                numGrad = Mid(strEquation, 4, 8)
                grad = CDbl(numGrad)
                Range("F" & j) = numGrad               ' Cells F112 to 149 get filled with the 4 point gradient results
            Next


    Else

    End If

Next
```

Comment: A screenshot could be of use for the understanding of the question.

Comment: `Cells(i & "26:" & "i" & "66").Select` is not valid...

Comment: Thanks Cody. Worked out I had made a mess of row and column identities.